# Hide notifications for MediaSessionCompat

Tags: android, wear-os, android-mediasession

I am using a MediaSessionCompat to get volume key events and play/pause
however,

I do not want to have the notification show on the watch, since I don't play anything and if possible, also don't show the volume change bar since I am not planning to change the volume, just change my internal state.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. Proverbs 23:7 says

> As a man thinketh in his heart, so is he

It's all in the mind bro.

Comment: awesome, Any idea how ?